# Can't add second google account to google calendar app

Tags: sync, google-calendar

I have one google account for my android phone. Now I set up a work email at gmail to use the shared calendar and keep things separated. For convenience I downloaded the google calendar app to display events from the calendar on my phone. I followed the steps to add another google account to my phone via **Settings -> Accounts -> Add Account -> Google**. Everything worked out fine, but on the google calender no events are shown. When I go to **Settings -> Accounts -> Google -> workaccount** I can't see the toggle for Calendar syncing. In the phone account I see this though.

With the same account I added the calendar to thunderbird using lightning and followed the procedure which worked out fine. Therefore I assume that the accounts calendar is visible.

My phone is a Oneplus One running CM 12.1 (Android 5.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for me was:

First activating *Device Information* in my *Google Activity Settings*.

Second I deleted the account from the phone and added it again. There was the toggle for syncing the calender.

Third I needed to allow google calendar to have access to the calendar storage, which was prohibited by default from the *Privacy Guard* in CM. This solved the *sync error* problem.

Now all my calendars and events show up on my phone.